# How to fix Google Sites Feed API?

Tags: php, google-api

I have a project where the Google Sites API stopped working in March 2019. I am continuously getting the following error message.

I have checked necessary things like API is enabled, scopes and Google Admin API access enabled.

> [26-Apr-2019 13:42:02 Europe/Minsk] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{
>    "error": "unauthorized_client",
>    "error_description": "Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested."
>   }
>
> 1. google-api-php-client\src\Google\Auth\OAuth2.php(314): Google_Auth_OAuth2->refreshTokenRequest(Array)
> 2. google-api-php-client\src\Google\Auth\OAuth2.php(239): Google_Auth_OAuth2->refreshTokenWithAssertion()
> 3. google-api-php-client\src\Google\Service\Resource.php(214): Google_Auth_OAuth2->sign(Object(Google_Http_Request))
> 4. google-api-php-client\src\Google\Service\Directory.php(1703): Google_Service_Resource->call('list', Array, 'Google_S in google-api-php-client\src\Google\Auth\OAuth2.php on line 363

I have not made any changes to my code and to the CREDENTIALS in the Google Developer Console or to the G Suite. What could have gone wrong for the API to stop working suddenly?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same surprising behavior with a NodeJS script using Google Sites API.

In GSuite developer admin console, some scopes for Google Sites have been removed (!) a few months ago, and must be replaced by a new one:

- Authenticate to https://console.developers.google.com
- In the top bar, choose the project corresponding to your app
- In the search field at the top, type "**Marketplace SDK**"
- Choose option **G Suite Marketplace SDK**
- Go to **Configuration**
- In section **OAuth 2.0 scopes** remove scopes:

  https://sites.google.com/feeds/site
  https://sites.google.com/feeds/activity
  https://sites.google.com/feeds/content
- Add scope:

  https://sites.google.com/feeds
- click **Save changes**

[image: GSuite developer console]

This [hint](https://support.google.com/business/thread/1904726?msgid=1904742) helped me. Using the [OAuth 2 API playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) shown a much more precise error when using an "old" scope (*Invalid legacy scope provided*)